# Highlight birthday in a referenced cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, microsoft-excel-2003

in Excel 2003
in worksheet1, I have a conditional formatting that highlights a cell when today is the birthday

in cell A1 date of Birth

in cell B1 age with the formula:
 `=DATEDIF($A1,TODAY(),"Y") & " Years, " & DATEDIF($A1,TODAY(),"YM") & " Months, " & DATEDIF ($A1,TODAY(),"MD") & " Days"`

with the conditional formatting:
`=TEXT($A1,"DD/MM")-TEXT(TODAY(),"DD/MM")=0`

which works perfectly

but in worksheet2, I have in cell B1 the formula
`=worksheet1!B1`

with the same conditional formatting which does not work

How can I make cell B1 in worksheet2 be highlighted when today is the birthday?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your conditional formatting for Sheet2? What you've described should work fine.

Comment: That conditional formatting formula cannot be right. B1 contains text, not a date, so the formula will return an error. It should refer to A1 instead of B1. Please check and update your question.

Comment: I am sorry, you are right, the formula in B1 is =TEXT($A1,"DD/MM")-TEXT(TODAY(),"DD/MM")=0
But this works only in sheet1, not sheet2

Comment: After reviewing  teylyn comment, I found the solution, in cell A1 in worksheet2, I also referred to  cell A1 of worksheet1; and this solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the comment of  teylyn, I found the solution, in cell A1 in worksheet2, I also referred to  cell A1 of worksheet1; and this solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a sheet reference to your conditional formatting formula on sheet 2 to refer to the source cell on sheet 1.

`=TEXT(Sheet1!$A1,"DD/MM")-TEXT(TODAY(),"DD/MM")=0`

Comment: Not in 2003, you can't. CF in 2003 can only use references on the same sheet or in named ranges.

Comment: you are right excel 2003 does not support referenced cells to other worksheet

Answer (score 1):

> in cell A1 date of Birth
> in cell B1 age with the formula
>
> with the conditional formatting:
> `=TEXT($B1,"DD/MM")-TEXT(TODAY(),"DD/MM")=0`

Having age in B1, are you sure your conditional formula works? Isn't it referring to A1??

As sheet2 contains age, not date of birth, use this formula:
`=FIND(B1," 0 Months, 0 Days")>0`

Comment: unfortunately it highlights all the cells. I also tried =FIND(B1," 0 Months 0 Days")=0, but it does not work

Comment: It's strange. Please post screenshots both on your data and the rules ( also from first Sheet)

Comment: This is a link to workshee1 and worksheet2
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=220F1BA8E872A001!116&authkey=!AKq6CdOBrC9ENfY&v=3&ithint=photo%2cJPG

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=220F1BA8E872A001!117&authkey=!AOswsdo6mx3Kbyw&v=3&ithint=photo%2cJPG

Comment: I've updated my formula, please check now

Comment: I tried your formula =FIND(B1," 0 Months, 0 Days")>0
 and also I tried =FIND(B1," 0 Months, 0 Days")=0
but they both did not work